# Compile Go for Windows Phone

Tags: go

I know it is possible to build Go for Android and iOS.

Can we build Go to be consumed by say, a Windows Phone app in the same was as Android and iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Go 1.5, Windows on ARM is not a supported target.